# PS3 clipping image with HDMI at 1080p

Tags: ps3

I have a PS3 connected to an HDTV Monitor using an HDMI cable configured for 1080p resolution.

My problem is that the image is being clipped on the edges. So certain things, like the box in which the times appears in the OS or the address bar when browsing the internet appear clipped on the screen.

I tried resetting the video configuration on my ps3 to factory conditions (by leaving the power button pressed until it beeps a second time) but the problem happens still.

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My TV (Samsung) has specially marked HDMI ports. There are 3 total, but one is marked `PC`. This port does not overscan, if the 'category' is also set to PC.

It sounds like your PS3 is broadcasting an exact resolution image, then the tv is trying to compensate for the [overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan). See if the HDMI Ports are labeled as such, and potentially name the port (in your TV menus) PC or Game (although it sounds like PC would be preferred in your case).

With all of that said, a friend has an older widescreen TV and is unable to disable overscan on it. He had to settle for changing it in his PC. The bad news is it [doesn't look like you can adjust overscan in the PS3 as a global setting at the moment](http://share.blog.us.playstation.com/ideas/2010/03/29/overscandisplay-adjustment/).