# Can I configure my PS3 to display videos not larger than my screen?

Tags: ps3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PS3 clipping image with HDMI at 1080p](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/ps3-clipping-image-with-hdmi-at-1080p)

I was watching some YouTube (*) videos on my brand new PS3, and I noticed that the video spans outside my TV screen, as shown in the following images:

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Can I configure the PS3 to not span beyond the TV limits? Is this a PS3 configuration or a YouTube App configuration? (I did notice that other apps do the same though)

I've tried every option I could find on my Sony Bravia, but it's no use.

(*) It also happens when using the Netflix app. I've yet to try games, as I still don't own any.

Comment: Are you sure it's your PS3 ? Because it might be just your TV that the display is zoomed.

Comment: @Warface, the other HDMI input (which is my cable tv) looks fine. Can that configuration be "input specific"? I'll check.

Comment: Or maybe try to go through the video output setting in the PS3 again and reconfigure it.

Comment: @Warface I didn't find anything in the Video Settings that looked like *zoom*, if you could provide a specific menu setting I could search it'd be great :)

Comment: Try to put your video output setting in the PS3 to 720p instead of 1080p to see if it fixed it.

Comment: @Warface same issue when forcing 720p

Answer (score 0):

**Adjust PS3:**

When you start your PS3, hold the button until it beeps a second time. This will force it to re-choose an output ratio, based on which output device you are using (AV/HDMI).

If the edges are still cut off, head into Settings->Video settings and try adjusting some of the settings manually (screen resolutions etc)

**Adjust TV:**

If the PS3 settings don't work, try and find a menu on your TV to adjust the picture output. Try to set the output to "Screen Fit" or "Best Fit" or "Auto Adjust" etc (instead of manual).

If Auto doesn't work you'll have to manually adjust the overscan properties to shrink/stretch the image into place - but try to avoid this if possible - 9 times out of 10 you won't need to do this.

These are just suggestions based on some troubleshooting I was doing when I moved my PS3 onto my new TV, I hope they help